# A slightly incorrect output whilst using classes in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working on an assignment in which you need to print out various basic calculations using classes by reading values from a text file.

The text file has these numbers:

> 2 5 7
>
> 3 2 1
>
> 4 4 4

The current code that I have (.cpp):

```
//CLIENT PROGRAM THAT WORKS WITH SQUARES

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "square_FML.h"
// include the file header for squares

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int s1, s2, s3;     // declare three int variables
    square sq1;// declare 4 objects of type square named sq1, sq2, sq3, and sq4 initializing the third one to 10
    square sq2;
    square sq3(10);
    square sq4;
    

    inFile.open("input21.txt");
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Could not open input file!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    // Access members using dot operator
    cout << "Before assigning values to the squares their sides are:" << endl;
    cout << "Square 1: " << sq1.getSide() << endl;      // Show the initial side of Square 1
    cout << "Square 2: " << sq2.getSide() << endl;      // Show the initial side of Square 2
    cout << "Square 3: " << sq3.getSide() << endl;      // Show the initial side of Square 3
    cout << endl << "............Starting to process the file............" << endl << endl;
    inFile >> s1 >> s2 >> s3;       // read 3 sides from the file (priming read)
    while(inFile)
    {
        cout << "Storing the values read into the side of squares..." << endl << endl;
        sq1.setSide(s1);    // store s1 in Square 1
        sq2.setSide(s2);        // store s2 in Square 2
        sq3.setSide(s3);        // store s3 in Square 3
        cout << "Displaying the new side of squares" << endl;
        cout << "Square 1: " << sq1.getSide() << endl;      // Show the new side of Square 1
        cout << "Square 2: " << sq2.getSide() << endl;      // Show the new side of Square 2
        cout << "Square 3: " << sq3.getSide() << endl;      // Show the new side of Square 3
        cout << endl << "Testing other member functions" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Area of Square 1: " << sq1.area() << endl;             // show the area of Square 1
        cout << "Perimeter of Square 2: " << sq2.perimeter() << endl;       // show the perimeter of Square 2
        if(sq1.equalTo(sq3))            // if Square 1 is equal to Square 3
            cout << "Square 1 and Square 3 are equal" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Square 1 and Square 3 are not equal" << endl;

        cout << "Area of (Square 2 + Square 3): " << sq2.plus(sq3) << endl; // Add the areas of Square 2 and Square 3
        cout << "Area of (Square 3 - Square 1): " << sq3.minus(sq1) << endl;    // Subtract the area of Square 1 from Square 3

        cout << "Creating a square double the size of Square 1" << endl;
        sq4 = sq1.increaseBy(2);        // Double the area of Square 1 and assign it to Square 4
        cout << "The side of the new square: " << sq4.getSide() << endl;        // Show the side of Square 4

        cout << "Creating a square of area equal to average area of Square 2 and Square 3" << endl;
        sq4 = sq2.avgSquare(sq3);           // Get the average area of Square 2 and Square 3 and assign it to Square 4
        cout << "The side of the new square: " << sq4.getSide() << endl;        // Show the side of Square 4
        cout << "The area of the new square: " << sq4.area()<< endl;        // Show the area of Square 4

        cout << endl << "..........Done with this set of values :-).........." << endl << endl;
        inFile >> s1 >> s2 >> s3;   // read next set of 3 sides
    }
    inFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the current code that contains the classes (.h):

```
// SPECIFICATION FILE FOR C++ CLASS Square
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class square
{
public:
    void setSide(int s);
    int getSide();
    square(int s);
    square();
    int plus(square sq);
    int minus(square sq);
    square increaseBy(int factor);
    square avgSquare(square sq);
    bool equalTo(square sq);
    int area();
    int perimeter();

private:
    int side;
};

void square::setSide(int s)
{
    side = s;
    
}

int square::getSide() {

    return side;
}

square::square() {

    side = 0;

}

square::square(int s) {

    side = s;
}

int square::plus(square sq) {

    return area() + sq.area();
}

int square::minus(square sq) {

    return area() - sq.area();

}

square square::increaseBy(int factor) {

    square ss(side * factor);
    return ss;

}

square square::avgSquare(square sq) {

    double avgArea = (area() + sq.area()) / 2;

    int newside = static_cast<int>(sqrt(avgArea));

    square ss(newside);

    return ss;

}

bool square::equalTo(square s) {

    if (side == s.side) {

    return true;

    }
    else {

    return false;

    }

}

int square::area() {
    return side * side;

}

int square::perimeter() {
    return 4 * side;

}
```

My current issue is that when it [prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM7ot.jpg)

(only showing the first two outputs) the 3 2 1 from the text file, the "The side of the new square: 1" should be a 2 and the "The area of the new square: 1" should be a 4. I was wondering what the current problem would be?

*I know that doing the using namespace std; isn't ideal but it's to save time right now.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you cast a double to an integer it truncates everything after the decimal. For example,

```
double x = 3.984;
int y = x; // y is 3
```

So the issue here is square::avgSquare. Static casting the double you get from sqrt(avgArea) to the int newside will cause the same truncation as shown above. Since sq2 and sq3 have areas 4 and 1, respectively, the reason you get 1 for both the side and area of the new square is that 4 + 1 = 5 and 5 / 2 = 2.5. But sqrt(2.5) is around 1.58 and that will be truncated to 1 when you cast it to int. So the new square returned by avgSquare will have side length 1.

Comment: How would I go about fixing that? Because I'm assuming that if I change newside to a double, I'd have to change a lot of other code to make it work.

Comment: Well if you are going to deal with averages then you're just gonna have to use doubles and change the rest of your code. Not really much else you can do.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that even if you did use doubles you wouldn't get the 2 for the side and 4 for the area that you expected. You'd get around 1.58 for the side and 2.5 for the area.

Comment: The first set of numbers worked because they didn't have to deal with decimals, is that correct? Because only those two numbers in the second run have that problem.

Comment: The first two numbers worked because 5^2 = 25 and 7^2 = 49. 25 + 49 = 74. 74 / 2 = 37. sqrt(37) truncates to 6. So it "worked" because you got lucky.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.